# How to know if flask migration changes reflected in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm creating a website using flask and python and in the development process, I added some tables to the models.py file. I went ahead and followed a tutorial to migrate the changes into my database using `flask db migrate`  and `flask db upgrade`. This should reflect the changes to the database right? But when I open the sqlite3 terminal and look up the tables, no changes are present. What could I be doing wrong?

[Running the migrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKo5v.png)

[Looking up the sqlite3 database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytcFP.png)

[My init.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4gAy.png)

[Migrations folder created containing the migration script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRvbu.png)

[The migrations script created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwgZd.png)

[Migrations script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7lTG.png)

Comment: Please provide more information about your code and how you set up the migration. If possible provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: more code has been added